# SQLite query failing

Tags: java, android

I have android code with an SQLite update query which works ok with Android 2.1 but seems to give a constraint error with 2.3.   Might the SQLite not be compatible with 2.3 and how can I tell which version of SQLite I am using?

Comment: whats the query? whats the error?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I tell which version of SQLite I am using?

`database.getVersion();` returns the version of the database.

For the rest of the issue, provide us with the logcat output.